# Deleting a hash from array of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes as following:

```
[{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}, {"k1"=>"v3", "k2"=>"5.1%"}]
```

Now, I want to first check whether the array contains a hash with key `"k1"` with value `"v3"`. If yes, then I want to delete that hash from the array.

The result should be:

```
[{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}]
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use [`Array#delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-delete_if):

```
arr = [{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}, {"k1"=>"v3", "k2"=>"5.1%"}]

arr.delete_if { |h| h["k1"] == "v3" }
#=> [{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}]
```

If there is no hash matching the condition, the array is left unchanged.

Comment: What if I want to do something in the else case, i.e. h["k1"] != "v3". How do we do that?

Answer (score 15):

You can do this with [***`Array#reject`***](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-reject)(If you don't want to modify the receiver)
 and also with [**`Array#reject!`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-reject-21)(If you want to modify the receiver)

```
arr = [{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}, {"k1"=>"v3", "k2"=>"5.1%"}]
p arr.reject { |h| h["k1"] == "v3" }
# >> [{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}]    

arr = [{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}, {"k1"=>"v3", "k2"=>"5.1%"}]
p arr.reject! { |h| h["k1"] == "v3" }
# >> [{"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}, {"k1"=>"v2", "k2"=>"-NA-"}]
```

Comment: Can I use this for rejecting multiple array elements ?